# Show tooltips for a TStringGrid cell

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to show tooltips on a TStringGrid control for each cell. The intention is to show the tooltip when the contents of the cell does not fit in the cell. Right now I am not even managing to make the tooltip show the correct content of the cell the mouse is hovering over.

What I tried so far is to use Application.hint and MyGrid.Hint and set it to the content of the cell. It looks like it always gets the content of a cell that was under the cursor half a second or so before the hint fires.

Even tried setting up a mousemove event and set the tooltip like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.GridMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  Row   : Integer;
  Column: TColumn;
  Col   : Integer;
  sHint : string;
begin
  Row := ProcessGrid.RowByPoint(X,Y);
  Column := ProcessGrid.ColumnByPoint(X,Y);
  if Assigned(Column) then
    Col := Column.Index
  else
    Col := -1;
  if (Row>-1) and (Col>-1) then
  begin
    sHint := ProcessGrid.Cells[Col,Row];
//    Application.Hint := sHint;
    ProcessGrid.Hint := sHint;
  end;
  Caption := Format('Col:%d Row:%d Hint: %s', [Col, Row, sHint]);
end;
```

The caption in the form for the code above displays the correct cell contents. The hint however does not and I'm having trouble understanding at the reason why. It must be something simple that I am overlooking.

Using Delphi 10.3.2 and trying to get this to work on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
procedure TForm1.GridMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Row   : Integer;
  Col   : Integer;
begin
  Grid.MouseToCell(X, Y, Col, Row);

  if (Row >= 0) and (Col >= 0) and (Grid.Hint <> Grid.Cells[Col, Row]) then
  begin
    Application.CancelHint;
    Grid.Hint:= Grid.Cells[Col,Row];
  end;
end;
```

the next code show the hint when the contents of the cell does not fit in the cell

```
procedure TForm1.GridMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  Row   : Integer;
  Col   : Integer;
begin
  Grid.MouseToCell(X, Y, Col, Row);

  if (Row >= 0) and (Col >= 0) and (Grid.Hint <> Grid.Cells[Col, Row]) and
     (Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[Col, Row]) > Grid.ColWidths[Col]) then
  begin
    Application.CancelHint;
    Grid.Hint:= Grid.Cells[Col,Row];
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ghostdz !

Had to tweak it a bit for Firemonkey.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.GridMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  Row   : Integer;
  Column: TColumn;
  Col   : Integer;
begin
  Row := Grid.RowByPoint(X,Y);
  Column := Grid.ColumnByPoint(X,Y);
  if Assigned(Column) then
    Col := Column.Index
  else
    Col := -1;

  Application.CancelHint;
  if (Row >= 0) and (Col >= 0) and (Grid.Hint <> Grid.Cells[Col, Row])
   and (Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[Col, Row]) > Column.Width)
   then
    Grid.Hint:= Grid.Cells[Col,Row];
  else
    Grid.Hint:= '';
end;
```

It's still a bit finicky. 
Sometimes it doesn't work. It also isn't pixel perfect, but I guess it has to do for now.